# Ran into a really weird problem with running localhost

Tags: windows, iis, .net-core

I started having this issue yesterday, but suddenly I'm unable to run even basic projects.  The project starts as expected, but then the browser always shows this in microsoft edge.  This is literally the boiler plate project generated when making a new application.  Has anyone else run into this problem and came up with a solution?

[image]

This is what I got my features set to...

[image]

Edit 1:

I've been able to confirm that I do not have the issue with older .NET Framework projects running off of IIS Express.  The issue seems to be purely when trying to run .NET Core applications using Kestrel.

Edit 2:

Went back and tried to change the port number to see if that made a difference. Unfortunately, it didn't seem to do anything.  (Swapped port number 5001 to 5501 just to see if it would load the template website.)

Also checked to see what is going on when trying to run the template program.  I can see port 5001 appear, but the state is TIME_WAIT and it never gets to established.

Edit 3:

When I start the .net core app it does get this far on the server...

[image]

Going back in time, the last thing I was doing before this problem started was creating a new user for my local SQL Server as well a setting up a database. I had already installed SSMS and didn't have any issues before that point, but I'm unsure how setting up a new user for a specific database on the SQL Server in SSMS would cause this problem.

I used Code first migrations via command line EF tools. I'm pretty sure this isn't related, as the problems began before I got to this point.

EDIT 4:

I tried accessing the default site via IP instead of using localhost. Oddly, 127.0.0.1:5001/mycontroller works, but trying to access it via localhost:5001/mycontroller does not work.

Edit 5:

I ran a test to see if a .net framework project can successfully launch and show up on localhost to make sure the issue is strictly with .NET Core applications using Kestrel.  As it turns out, running an older .NET Framework style project on IIS Express does work on localhost.

Comment: An error showed like that for `https://localhost:5001` means 1) you probably failed to launch Kestrel web server (who monitors that binding when `dotnet run` is called on an ASP.NET Core project, not IIS nor IIS Express). 2) Even if you run Kestrel on that binding, if the test certificate was not configured properly HTTPS connections cannot be made.

Comment: I did try dotnet dev-certs --clean followed by dotnet dev-certs https --trust.  I'm still getting the same results, though.

Comment: I've edited the post to remove the confusion on Kestral vs IIS / IIS Express.  I'm leaving the features screen shot up just in-case there is some relevance that I'm missing.

Comment: Is IE set as your default Browser? What happens if you use Edge, Chrome or Safari (if on an Apple platform)?